# SQL/PHP - Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, sql, sql-update, syntax-error

I have a database and I am trying to update a row of it, but i keep getting this error. on a previous program i used the same function, so i can't see what is going wrong and it's driving me mad! If anyone can see anything or help me out it would be much appreciated!

Here is the update function:

```
public function update($member){
   if ($member == null){
      throw new Exception("Member ID Required");   }  

    $id = $member->getId();
    if ($id == null){
        throw new Exception("Member ID Required");
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE member SET
        firstName = :firstName,
        lastName = :lastName,
        dob = :dob,
        email = :email,
        gender = :gender,
        skillLevel = :skillLevel,
        Where id = :id";

    $params = array(
        'id' => $member->getId(),
        'firstName' => $member->getFirstName(),
        'lastName' => $member->getLastName(),
        'dob' => $member->getDOB(),
        'email' => $member->getEmail(),
        'gender' => $member->getGender(),
        'skillLevel' => $member->getSkillLevel(),
    );
      $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
    $status = $stmt->execute($params);
    if ($status != true){
        $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
        throw new Exception("Could Not Add Member: " . $errorInfo[2]);
    }
    return $stmt->rowCount();
    }
```

Here is the edit page it is getting it's data from

```
<?php

require_once('member.php');
require_once('MemberDAO.php');
require_once('editFormValidator.php');

$validator = new editFormValidator();

if ($validator->validate($_POST)){
$i = $_POST['memberID'];
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$skillLevel = $_POST['skillLevel'];
$skillLevelString = implode(", ", $skillLevel);
$member = new Member ($i,$firstName, $lastName, $dob, $email, $gender,     $skillLevelString);
$dao = new MemberDAO();
$dao->update($member);
header ('Location: viewMember.php');
}
else{
require_once 'editMember.php';
}
?>
```

here is the full error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Where id = '4'' at line 8' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ChessClub/MemberDAO.php:115 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ChessClub/MemberDAO.php(115): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ChessClub/edit.php(20): MemberDAO->update(Object(Member)) #2 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ChessClub/MemberDAO.php on line 115
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a superfluous comma here:

```
skillLevel = :skillLevel,
```